# Grid With Group and Sub-group selection in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i m developing an web app and using jquery for my client side scripting.

i want i grid with following features.

1.group and sub-group selection **!important**
2.on selection of group header i want to select all its child sub-groups **!important**
3.Search Features.
4.Loading data from web services. **!important**

please tell me any grid which provide me all this features which can be implemented with minimum efforts.

i have tried jqxgrid but there i cant find my concerned **2 point**

Comment: what is a `group and sub-group selection`? can you examples of them? Also refer to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for software recommendations.

Comment: groups are like  parent node having its child which are cascaded under it.